# Accessing unique_ptr in unit tests that has been moved in the constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

What's the approach towards accessing `unique_ptr` in unit tests which has already been moved in the constructor?
I was thinking of creating a `shared_ptr` alongside `unique_ptr` and access `shared_ptr` in unit tests but I am afraid that would be UB as well.

```
|struct Base
{
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

struct B : public Base
{
    MOCK_METHOD(int, bar, (), (override));
};

class A
{
   std::unique_ptr<B> _ptrB;

   public:
   A(std::unique_ptr<B> ptr) : _ptrB(std::move(ptr))
   {
      // A takes ownership of Utest::ptrB now
   }
};

struct Utest
{ 
  Utest()
  {
    ptrA = std::make_shared<A>(std::move(ptrB));
  }

  std::shared_ptr<A> ptrA;
  std::unique_ptr<B> ptrB = std::make_unique<B>();
};

TEST_F(Utest, testA)
{
    // can't access ptrB since it's been moved
    EXPECT_CALL(*ptrB, bar()).WillOnce(Return(100));  // error: Process finished with exit code 11
}
```

**Edit:**

I was able to get around it with this solution where I use the private member `A::_ptrB` after it's moved and downcast it to type `B` and use it in `EXPECT_CALL`.

Question though is: can I move the downcasting part to the constructor so I wouldn't have to 'repeat' the steps in all other unit tests? Or are there better ways?

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

struct BaseMock : public Base
{
    MOCK_METHOD(int, bar, (), (override));
};

class A
{
   std::unique_ptr<BaseMock> _ptrB;
   friend class Utest;

   public:
   A(std::unique_ptr<BaseMock> ptr) : _ptrB(std::move(ptr))
   {
      // A takes ownership of Utest::ptrB now
   }
   
};

struct Utest
{ 
  Utest()
  {
    ptrA = std::make_shared<A>(std::move(ptrB));
  }

  std::shared_ptr<A> ptrA;
  std::unique_ptr<BaseMock> ptrB = std::make_unique<BaseMock>();
};

TEST_F(Utest, testA)
{
    BaseMock* ptr = dynamic_cast<BaseMock*>(_ptrB.get());
    EXPECT_CALL(*ptr, bar()).WillOnce(Return(100)); 
}
```

Comment: you discard `ptr` in `A` ctor. Looks like you forgot to store it. If you store it in `A` then you can just use it.

Comment: `TEST_F` would be within the context of `Utest` class no? I was thinking of accessing the members directly within `Utest` so I don't have to instantiate them in each test. I am supposed to store it but I didn't here as it's not relevant to the main question I reckon

Comment: You wrote very convoluted code that would be nightmare to support (if yo make it work). You better describe what you want to achieve. In current situation your code does not make any sense - you create `ptrB` then pass it to nowhere to get that content destroyed.

Comment: Okay. Just to clear further confusion, `ptrB` is being "moved" now into `_ptrB`...

Comment: Now you can keep raw pointer to content of `ptrB`, you need to be sure that you do not use it after the instance of `class A` destroyed

Answer (score 1):

With regular test, you might do:

```
TEST(testA)
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> ptrB = std::make_unique<B>();
    EXPECT_CALL(*ptrB, bar()).WillOnce(Return(100));
    A a(std::move(ptrB));
    // Do test with `a`
}
```

Comment: Cool, that works. Is there a better way though to not having to "duplicate" the same lines in case there are 100 other unit tests? Something can be done in the `Utest` ctor?

Comment: @xyf I believe that's what gtest's SetUp and TearDown methods on test fixtures are for, what don't you use them?